# Python 2.7 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, append, string-formatting, typeerror

I've produced the following bit of code for python but for some reason I can't work out why it's returning the error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple`

I've had a look under  but I can't see what I'm doing wrong :S

```
temp_appended_data = []

def runme():
    global temp_appended_data

    def test():
        return "testdata"

    def no():
        return "22453.32214"

    def time():
        return "22:12"

    def name():
        return "george"

    temp_appended_data.append("""test example <br>
                                Test: % <br>
                                no: % <br> 
                                time: % <br>
                                name: % <br>
                                """) % (test(),no(),time(),name())

    print temp_appended_data

runme()
```

Anyone able to see and fix what I've done wrong?

Thanks
- Hyflex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None`.  You probably wanted to move your parenthesis so that your formatting a string them passing it to `append` rather than appending an unformatted string and then trying to format `None`.

```
temp_appended_data.append("""test example <br>
                            Test: %s <br>
                            no: %s <br> 
                            time: %s <br>
                            name: %s <br>
                            """ % (test(),no(),time(),name()))
```

Also, `%` isn't a valid replacement field.  You probably meant to use `%s`.

Comment: @Ber -- Right.  I didn't notice that one.  I was just addressing the first problem in the traceback.  :)

Comment: @Bakuriu -- When you see stuff that blatantly wrong on one of my posts, feel free to fix it :)  But, thanks for the comment making me aware of my overzealous `%` substitution :)

Comment: Thank you ever so much, I had tried the %s but changed to % to try and leave it unformatted.

I now have a relating issue when appending more than 1 item to the list/array I am unable file.write(temp_append_data)

How should I fix that?

Comment: @Hyflex -- maybe `file.writelines(temp_append_data)` or `file.write('\n'.join(temp_append_data))` although it's hard to know without knowing exactly what you're up to.

Comment: I tried the second option you gave and it worked perfectly, pure genius.

Thank you very much.